# Unable to read data from Firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Just trying to get url the url that I have stored in that node. It is a audio file url that I have stored in the storage.

```
ValueEventListener changeListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String change = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
        if(snapshot.hasChildren()){
            if(snapshot.hasChild("song")){
                String song_url = (String) snapshot.child("song").getValue();
               
                Log.d("tansen","[SUCCESS] url: "+song_url);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("tansen","[FAILURE] snapshot.hasChild()");
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("tansen","[FAILURE] snapshot.hasChildren()");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
};
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("/tansen-37eb3-default-rtdb/song");
dbRef.addValueEventListener(changeListener);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: In addition to what Alex asked, please: 1) Edit your question to include the output of the `Log` statements in your code. 2) Implement `onCancelled` as you're ignoring potential errors. At its minimum it should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.